# Uncaught TypeError for " .push in array "

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am trying to use `.push` concept in `array`, heres the code which I tried every thing went fine until I added `.push` in a `for` loop

```js
var percentage;

function calculator(bill) {
  if (bill < 50) {
    percentage = .20;
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
    percentage = .15;
  } else {
    percentage = .1;
  }
  return percentage * bill;
}
var bill = [250, 112, 45];

function total() {
  var totalAmount = [];
  var totalValue = [];
  for (i = 0; i < bill.length; i++) {
    var tip = calculator(bill[i])
    totalValue = bill[i] + tip;
    console.log("The Tip of " + bill[i] + " is = " + tip + " & the Total Value is " + totalValue);
    for (u = 0; u < bill.length; u++) {
      totalValue.push(u);
      totalAmount.push(totalValue);
    }
  }
  console.log(totalAmount);
}
total();
```

This is the error what the browser is throwing in the Console `Uncaught TypeError: totalValue.push is not a function`

Comment: The Fiddle link is here : https://jsfiddle.net/0r329cas/1/

Comment: `totalValue = bill[i] + tip;` <-- because it is no longer an array so `totalValue.push(u);` fails

Comment: The cause of your error is that you're setting `totalValue = bill[i] + tip`. Where `bill[i]` is an integer, and `tip` is float. So `totalValue` is now a number variable, not an array.

Comment: tip is defined at line no.19, any solution to use the `.push` @fubar

Comment: why are you pushing to an array what you clearly are just trying to sum up

Comment: I want to push the `totalValue` to an `array`. so, for that `array` I developed this code. @epascarello

Comment: but you are overridding the array variable with the sum. `var totalValue = [];` < array and you do `totalValue = bill[i] + tip;` <-- no longer array and then you do `totalValue.push(u);` <-- assume it is an array

Comment: I solved it, I created another `for` loop unnecessarily. @epascarello

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain, yeah I spotted that immediately after I'd written my comment. It's early here, so my eyes weren't reading too well :/

Comment: Did you debug this code before posting? Stepping thru the code you would have seen that totalValue was no longer an array.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I created another for loop unnecessarily.

```js
var percentage;

function calculator(bill) {
  if (bill < 50) {
    percentage = .20;
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
    percentage = .15;
  } else {
    percentage = .1;
  }
  return percentage * bill;
}
var bill = [250, 112, 45];

function total() {
  var totalAmount = new Array();
  var totalValue = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < bill.length; i++) {
    var tip = calculator(bill[i])
    totalValue = bill[i] + tip;
    console.log("The Tip of " + bill[i] + " is = " + tip + " & the Total Value is " + totalValue);
      totalAmount.push(totalValue);
  }
  console.log(totalAmount);
}
total();
```

Comment: If you initilizate the `totalValue` as an `Array` don't convert it to a number `totalValue = bill[i] + tip;`. This make you the code slower. You can init as 0. Ex: `var totalValue = 0;`

Comment: delete `var totalValue = new Array();` and do `var totalValue = bill[i] + tip;`